# Angular expression evaluate as NAN inside an attribute

Tags: angularjs

I have this script inside html file (a view file):

```
{{dashData.smsData.userSmsPercent}}
<div class="easy-pie-chart txt-color-orangeDark" data-percent="{{dashData.smsData.userSmsPercent}}" data-pie-size="50">
    <span class="percent percent-sign"></span>
</div>
```

The expression {{dashData.smsData.userSmsPercent}} returns "1" on the first one, and NAN inside the "data-percent" attribute.
Have any idea why this weird behavior?

Comment: Is it type string or int/number?

Comment: I tried Both string and numbers, but didn't work. it gives NAN.

Comment: looks fine for me - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pbajAz

Comment: Thanks for the working test code, Nega.
I suppose you are right, the code is fine, and maybe this happens because of the 'easy-pie' plugin. I still have this issue though, but I moved on without using it.